# SharePoint: ListViewByQuery.RenderControl() or SPView.RenderAsHtml()... not showing aggregrates

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to dynamically change what List, columns, aggrgrates are shown on a WebPart... and so we are rendering an html table by using ListViewByQuery.RenderControl(). However, it seems that this method does not render the aggregrates as you would see them if you navigated to a view inside of the SharePoint site itself. We tried SPView.RenderAsHtml() as well... also no joy... please tell me that there is a solution to this very annoying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up creating an instance of XsltListViewWebPart instead. Calling RenderControl() on this does support aggregrates, etc. It went something like this:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(list.DefaultView.GetViewXml());
// etc
XsltListViewWebPart wp = new XsltListViewWebPart();
wp.XmlDefinition = xmlDocument.OuterXml;
// etc
wp.DataBind();

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
                {
                    wp.RenderControl(writer);
                }

                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
```

A little more complicated than that.... but that's the general idea...

Answer (score 0):

you might try a combination of 2 webparts: 1) out of the box list view webpart that displays the views as they are in the list 2) a UI-less webpart that is placed on the same page and updates the view of the list view webpart's query according to the query of the associated view. the update should be done via webpart manager of the page both webparts are placed into.

good luck.